# IOS: tab bar swipe animation not working well

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe

I have 3 View controllers and Every screen has a UISwipeGestureRecognizer for the swipes. 
But When I swipe between these view controller 
it's not very smooth.

**I'm Using Xcode 7.0**

[image: Click Here to see the Image]

**here's My Code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedRightButton:)];
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedLeftButton:)];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

- (IBAction)tappedRightButton:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [rootVC.tabBarController selectedIndex];

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex + 1];

    //To animate use this code
    CATransition *anim= [CATransition animation];
    [anim setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [anim setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [anim setDuration:1];
    [anim setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    [self.tabBarController.view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"fadeTransition"];
} 

- (IBAction)tappedLeftButton:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [rootVC.tabBarController selectedIndex];

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex - 1]; 

    CATransition *anim= [CATransition animation];
    [anim setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [anim setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];

    [anim setDuration:1];
    [anim setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                              kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    [self.tabBarController.view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"fadeTransition"];
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to navigate between screens with swipes?

Comment: and how does it look on a device ?

Comment: @Moshe Yes, I'm Trying to navigate between screens with swipe, it's working fine but it's not smooth as you could see in the image

Comment: @YvesLeBorg as showing in the image, as i said it's working fine but not very smooth, I'm trying to make it like this article https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers

Comment: @AssamAl-Zookery I understand what you are trying to do. I ask if you tried on a real device, just to eliminate the fact that the rendering *"performance"* could be related to running in a a simulator running on some MacBook.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Yes, I just did test on my iphone device I'm still having the same issue with swipe. Thank you for your help

Comment: Look at UIPanGestureRecognizer.